# Dynamic include directive in a Makefile

Tags: makefile

Let's consider this Makefile:

```
.SUFFIXES:
.DEFAULT_GOAL := all

out=foo

clean: 
    rm -f vars.mk
    rm -f $(out)

vars.mk: vars.mk.default
    @echo "Regenerating $@..."
    cp $< $@ # Let's assume the translation is much complex than a cp

-include vars.mk

ifeq ($(filter foo,$(FOO)),)
    $(error FOO undefined)
endif

all: $(out)

$(out): vars.mk   
    echo "Cow says: I am not a $(FOO)." > $@
```

And the file `vars.mk.default`

```
FOO = foo bar
```

I would like to regenerate my targets if `vars.mk.default` is updated. Furthermore, as double check, one must check that `foo` exists in `$(FOO)`.

How to force make to regenerate `vars.mk` if `vars.mk.default` is updated?

In other words, I would like this output:

```
$ make clean
$ sed 's/dog/cat/' vars.mk.default
$ make foo
Regenerating vars.mk...
echo "Cow says: I am not a cat" > all

$ make foo
make: Nothing to be done for 'all'.

$ sed 's/cat/dog/' vars.mk.default
$ make
Regenerating vars.mk...
echo "Cow says: I am not a dog" > all

$ rm vars.mak
$ make 
Regenerating vars.mk...
echo "Cow says: I am not a dog" > all
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> My goal is to regenerate my targets if vars.mk.default is updated.

In this case make your targets depend on that file, but filter it out in the recipes, e.g.

```
foo.o : foo.cc vars.mk.default
    $(COMPILE) $(filter-out vars.mk.default,$^)
```

> In the case vars.mk does not exist, make fails on the ifeq and do not generates vars.mk.

Make is going to build `vars.mk` and restart, see [How Makefiles Are Remade](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Remaking-Makefiles) for more details.

So, to avoid that error, check first if `FOO` is defined with `ifdef FOO`.

Comment: Unfortunately this will not take in account the `include vars.mk` directive :(

Comment: @nowox Could you elaborate?

Comment: Interesting. I guess I am wrong and your solution works. I am just wondering why the `foo.o : foo.cc | vars.mk.default` does not work?

Answer (score 2):

To avoid failing if vars.mk doesn't exist, just check for it first:

```
ifeq ($(wildcard vars.mk),vars.mk)
  ifeq ($(filter foo,$(FOO)),)
    $(error FOO undefined)
  endif
endif
```

Comment: Thank for your answer. The check was more a guard if something bad happens. My main point is to automatically regenerate `vars.mk` if `vars.mk.default` is updated as showed on my edit.

Answer (score 0):

A couple of things.   First, you should put a `-` in front of the include to prevent a warning from popping up if the file does not exist:

```
-include vars.mk
```

This will not cause a fatal error if vars.mk is not generated, but because the vars.mk rule would fail in this case, you would get your error from there.

You can then check if `$(FOO)` contains `foo` from within a recipe:

```
checkForFoo: vars.mk
    @[[ $(FOO) =~ .*foo.* ]] || false 

all:checkForFoo
```

The recipe is only run after the vars.mk was generated and included, so it should only fail in the conditions you want.

Comment: I modified my question and added `-` in front of the include.